# Аутентификация без логина и пароля

Tags: аутентификация

Всем привет!
Сразу к делу!

Нужно реализовать некий сайт/сервер с выбором редиректов(зараннее созданы и выбираются списком вручную для каждого приложения) на другие сайты
для  приложениий на android.

На самом сайте есть авторизация для юзеров.

Нужна авторизация без введения логина и пароля для приложений (в них реализован браузер который просто ведет на указанный заранее сайт/сервер.

Нужно чтобы сервер понимал кто к нему пришел(есть идеи передать bundle id приложения или вводить их вручную в бд,) но как его передать на сервер не понятно
хотел сделать на основе заголовков, которые приходят к apache при подключении

127.0.0.1 [16/Jul/2018:13:47:07 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 255 "http://fuckingpaaage/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"

А как из этих заголовков потом доставать нужную информацию (bundle id) я не нашел решения.

Так как при сборке приложения в них вставляется URL на главный сайт сервер,
были идеи генерировать уникальные шорты и вставлять в приложение url типа example.com + short и от этого плясать чтобы серв их индентифицировал именно по этим шортам и аутентифицировал, как реализовать это не знаю. ибо нуб.

Ну а дальше, на основании этого сервер должен редиректить того, кто пришел, на 
заранее выбранный вручную редирект.

Для примера - есть три приложения. оба ведут на сайт X. 1е редиректим на сайт Y, 2е на сайт Z, 3е на сайт A и тд. И эти значения постоянно нужно будет менять вручную, выбирая из списка редиректы.

Есть еще такой момент, чтобы к этому сайту/серверу могли подключатся только приложения и определенный круг лиц (подключение для определенных пользователей уже есть).

P.S в самих приложениях ничего менять не вариант. уникальный у них только bundle/application id типа "com.example.app". поэтому варианты с приписыванием им уникального айди или еще какой инфы не подходят.
Прошу помочь мне в этом вопросе.

Comment: Используйте механизм токенов.

Comment: спасибо! не могли поподробнее рассказать где копать куда смотреть? может небольшой пример реализации

Comment: [Пожалуйста](https://gist.github.com/zmts/802dc9c3510d79fd40f9dc38a12bccfc)

Comment: @GARRYTEAM мне кажется вам нужно почитать про то, Как посылать запросы с андроид приложения на сервер, [http://java-help.ru/android-get-post/](вот к примеру). Вы отправляете запрос серверу с переменной, он ловит и в ответ выдает ссылку на редирект.